# How to use squid proxy server to modify html page before sending to client

Tags: python, html, http, proxy, squid

I am looking to setup a proxy server and I want to run some python script(or any other language) to filter out some content on the html pages, the client requests through proxy server.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at ICAP and ECAP: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/ICAP and http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/eCAP. They accomplish the same goal - ICAP is via an external helper daemon (which you'd need to code on your own) and ECAP uses plugins.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the task of Squid to modify your HTML.

Use something like

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ext_filter.html

Comment: Isn't this a server side thing? can you please explain in more detail.

Comment: Actually content adoption is a perfectly normal task for Squid, see ICAP and ECAP.